# Segmentation Fault (core dumped) when using scanf and r+ file

Tags: c, file-io, io

I've been banging my head for a while on this problem:
If I write

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    int cnum, c1;
    FILE *fp;
    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("count of numbers: ");
    scanf ("%i",&cnum);
    printf("echo123");
    fp = fopen("randomnumbers.txt", "w");
    fprintf(fp, "%d ", cnum);
    for(c1=0; c1<cnum; c1++)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%d ", rand()%1000);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

I get a segmentation fault during the execution of scanf. If I open the file with "w" however everything works fine. I don't get the relation between these two things but I've isolated the code and proven that this is indeed what is triggering the segfault.
Echo123 never gets printed.

Comment: It's *very* unlikely that scanf() is giving segfault. It's *most* likely what you do (or don't do) after fopen() that gives problem.

Comment: can you post your complete code here

Comment: Why would you get a fault on `scanf` attributable to the way you use `fopen` when `fopen` has yet to be executed? The first four lines of code within `main()` work perfectly (well almost, `cnum` is unreferenced).

Comment: `r+` in `fopen()` will open an existing file for reading and writing. If the file does not exist it will not create it. Reading and writing on a failed `fopen()` in `r+` mode will crash. `w+` is also reading and writing except it will create a file if non-existent.

Comment: compiles and runs fine for me, make sure you have write permission to the current directory.

Comment: After doing `fopen` add in `if ( !fp ) { fprintf(stderr, "failed to open file\n"); return 1;`  .

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you don't see "echo123" does not mean that your program segfaulted before that line. Most likely that printout is buffered and will be flushed later, maybe when printing a newline.

To avoid buffered output, try `fprintf(stderr,"echo123\n");` instead.